# this.$state is undefined when trying to access $state inside a tree menu item click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `"angular-ui-tree": "^2.22.5"`

Error when I click on the `Do something` menu item ..

```
TypeError: this.$state is undefined
```

How can I pass a reference to `$state` to my function ..

MyController:

```
export class MyController {

  public treeMenuItems = [
    {
      'handleClick': this.doSomething,
      'name': 'Do something'
    }
  ];
  public treeMenuPopover = {
    'items': this.treeMenuItems,
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': 'Actions'
  };

  constructor(public $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {}

  public doSomething() {
    this.$state.go('my.state');
  }
}
MyController.$inject = ['$state'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about how `this` works in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

For your code try

```
export class MyController {

  public treeMenuItems = [
    {
      'handleClick': this.doSomething,
      'name': 'Do something'
    }
  ];
  public treeMenuPopover = {
    'items': this.treeMenuItems,
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': 'Actions'
  };

  constructor(public $state: ng.ui.IStateService) {
    this.doSomeThing = this.doSomething.bind(this);
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.$state.go('my.state');
  }
}
MyController.$inject = ['$state'];
```

This way you bind the correct this the function `doSomething`. So whenever it is called its `this` will be consistent.

Comment: Error `Cannot find name 'doSomething'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.doSomething'?` .. in the constructor. And using what the error suggests, gives me the original error

Comment: yes correct, my bad, I have updated the question. 

Or you can try yo extract it out of the class.

Comment: "extract it"? not sure what you mean

Comment: By extract I mean sth like 

`const doSomething = function () {...}`

Above your class.

But adding the this is more coherent with how other methods are defined, so you should stick to it.

I have reflected this in the answer.